# SendMessage Max Receivers

Tags: windows, delphi, sendmessage

I have a main application and 4 client applications, I communicate back to the main application using `SendMessage`.

I can use any three of the client apps without any problems but as soon as I add a forth I get access violations and stackoverflow errors.

My question: is there a maximum for the number of apps that can send using `SendMessage` to a single application?

I am using Delphi XE2 and Windows 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, is there a maximum for the number of apps that can send using SendMessage to a single application?

No there is not. Your problem is not related to the number of processes sending messages.

One likely explanation for an access violation when processing messages is that your message contains a pointer to memory that is only valid in the address space of the sending process. But that's a wild guess since we have no code.

Comment: after doing a lot of googling i found the same result, there doesnt seem to be a max number, however it is good practice to finish with the message event as quick as possible to prevent a back up of information

Comment: Correct. If necessary only dump the message in some queue and return, then let another thread process that queue.

Comment: @Jan, then would be enough to use `PostMessage` instead.

Comment: @TLama That would stop the sending process from blocking. But if the message processing took a long time, then there'd be problems if messages were posted at a higher rate than they were processed.

Comment: @David, I know, but dump the message in a queue and process it in a different thread just breaks the blocking mode. In that case I would rather post messages in both ways and wait for some confirmation message on the sender's side (wait until receiver confirms processing).